# How can I fix the error "An error has occurred. See the log file null" in ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to install eclipse on ubuntu 16.10. After extracting the zar file when I try to run the installer, it shows the message "An error has occurred. See the log file null". How can I fix this error?

Comment: Not the place to ask this. Try https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @abhipil Agree that askubuntu is a better place, but this question is not off-topic here: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**." Installing Eclipse falls under "tools used primarily for programming.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid wasting time in installation and just start using tar.gz eclipse binaries we can download it from eclipse official website.

What ever version is suitable to you.

https://howto-ubuntunew.blogspot.in/2016/09/how-to-install-eclipse-ide-on-ubuntu.html

try above link and start developing you application or programming.